# ADF Model: Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter

Tags: jsf, web-applications, war, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Just facing a problem since some days.

`Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter`

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>adfBindings</filter-name>
    <filter-class>oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Libs

[image]

May be someone already faces this issue?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: did you install ADF runtime libs on your server? if you did this did your ADF runtime libs compatible with your server version?

Comment: Yes i did. But the problem persists

Comment: You face this problem even if you run it in your embedded weblogic?

Comment: @AmrGawish  Yes I face this problem by running the app the embedded wls

Comment: Can you provide full error stack. May be this error caused by some other means? Everything else looks okay. Also, have you tried to install copy of jdeveloper into different directory (be careful with the spaces in the path) and running this application from this fresh install? Also please provide version number, you are using there.